# User enter 5 characters and averge sums out the 5 numbers in C

Tags: c, input

I been having issues having my C code work. I have 1 warning, which states Warning: too many arguments for format. I am a beginner in C so I haven't encountered this issue yet. Any ideas on how to fix it and I cannot use conditions as I am in the beginning segment of my course learning from the start. I just need to know what I did wrong so I can fix the issue. Here's the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber;
    float fourthNumber, fifthNumber;

    float sumAverage1 = (firstNumber+secondNumber+thirdNumber);
    float sumAverage2 = (fourthNumber+fifthNumber);


    long a = 1000000000;
    long b = 1250000000;
    long c = 1500000000;
    long d = 1750000000;
    long e = 2000000000;

        printf("A is %li\n", a);
        printf("B is %li\n", b);
        printf("C is %li\n", c);
        printf("D is %li\n", d);
        printf("E is %li\n", e);

        printf("Enter 5 Random numbers and guess what the total will be summed up when program runs.\n");
        printf("You cannot enter a decimal integer and enter numbers below 100.\n");
            scanf("%f", &firstNumber);
            scanf("%f",&secondNumber);
            scanf("%f",&thirdNumber);
            scanf("%f",&fourthNumber);
            scanf("%f",&fifthNumber);

            printf("Your numbers average out to:\n", sumAverage1+sumAverage2/5);

    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the last `printf` you have forgotten to put a format specifier for the number (`%f` I guess...).

Comment: forgot to add #include <stdlib.h> at top when I added system pause.

Comment: You also calculate the sums before getting any input.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't notice it.  Stayed up late last night, brain dead haha. Thank you and I will vote up when it allows.

Comment: The code is still not functional.  I moved:  scanf("%f", &firstNumber);
            scanf("%f",&secondNumber);
            scanf("%f",&thirdNumber);
            scanf("%f",&fourthNumber);
            scanf("%f",&fifthNumber);


            float sumAverage1 = (firstNumber+secondNumber+thirdNumber);
            float sumAverage2 = (fourthNumber+fifthNumber);
            printf("Your numbers average out to:%f\n", (sumAverage1+sumAverage2)/5);

Comment: Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this will solve all your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
float firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber,sumAverage1;
float fourthNumber, fifthNumber,sumAverage2;
long a = 1000000000;
long b = 1250000000;
long c = 1500000000;
long d = 1750000000;
long e = 2000000000;
printf("Enter 5 Random numbers and guess what the total will be summed up when program runs.\n");
printf("You cannot enter a decimal integer and enter numbers below 100.\n");
scanf("%f",&firstNumber);
scanf("%f",&secondNumber);
scanf("%f",&thirdNumber);
scanf("%f",&fourthNumber);
scanf("%f",&fifthNumber);

sumAverage1 = (firstNumber+secondNumber+thirdNumber);
sumAverage2 = (fourthNumber+fifthNumber);

    printf("A is %li\n", a);
    printf("B is %li\n", b);
    printf("C is %li\n", c);
    printf("D is %li\n", d);
    printf("E is %li\n", e);
        printf("Your numbers average out to:%f\n", (sumAverage1+sumAverage2)/5);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I ran this on my Visual Studio and it works just fine. Hope it Solves your Problem.

Comment: Hey, the issue I am getting is a negative number as a output I need it to round up the numbers the user enters. I know there is a simple way to fix it, but I am a super novice in C.

Comment: Please include what inputs you are entering and what output you are getting.

Comment: inputs I enter is anything above 1 and below 100 and the output I get every time is -1.#QQ as the sumAverage

Comment: Did you try what i have written here? i ran it with different values and it is giving valid output. just copy my code and run it. say if it gives same error.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried yours out.  It shows it working. Thanks, for the help Vishwajeet.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 printf("Your numbers average out to:\n", sumAverage1+sumAverage2/5);
```

Has an argument but no format specifier. Also, that expression is unparenthesized; the division has higher precedence than the addition, so what you're calculating is `sumAverage1+(sumAverage2/5)`, which is integer division, which is probably not what you want.

What you probably want is:

```
printf("Your numbers average out to: %f\n", (double)(sumAverage1+sumAverage2)/5.0);
```

Comment: I've added those edits. The scanf isn't working for when it asks the user for the 5 scanf inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the printf format specifier, but your `scanf` does not capture the extra dangling newline. You need to either clear the buffer, `fflush(stdin)` after each `scanf()` or you need an extra `scanf("%c")` to get rid of the newline character.

See [scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Comment: `scanf("%c")` gets the next character after the number, which _might_ be a newline.  It might not.  It is simple the next character.  `fflush(stdin)` is a non-portable way to empty `stdin`.  "scanf does not capture the extra dangling newline." misleads as `scanf("%f",&secondNumber);` will consume any prior white-space first, including the previous line's leftover newline.